# How to create different animation states (walk, run, idle...) in the same file?

Tags: animation

I made my character IDLE animation by assigning Actions to my model meshes.

The problem comes when i want another animation, let's call it the WALK animation.

If i'm not mistaken adding another Action to a model mesh, that already has one, seems to create a NLA Stack adding the old Action inside.

The Dope Sheet seems to only display the keyframes from the old Action, the one that has been addeed to the NLA Stack. Then how i can edit the new Action?

I thought i would be able to have one timeline per each animation state?

EDIT: So pressing the X button is definetly a step forward, it Unlinks the Action from the Mesh.

Now i can create a new Action in the Mesh without modifying the previous one.

What was happening in my case is that as i was not pressing the X button to Unlik, a NLA Stack was created.

But there's still something i don't really get, if i want to display the previous animation i need to Link, every time, the old Actions to the Meshes? There isn't a "Group Actions" functionality?

Comment: When you are in the *Dopesheet* / *Action Editor*, if you want to create a new action you can either click on the *Create New Action* button, or click on the *X* on its right and then click *New*. If you choose *Create New Action* it will keep the same keyframes as the last action you've created, you can delete these keyframes or change them, it won't affect the previous action.

Comment: So pressing the X button is definetly a step forward, it Unlinks the Action from the Mesh. Now i can create a new Action in the Mesh without modifying the previous one. What was happening in my case is that as i was not pressing the X button to Unlik, a NLA Stack was created. But there's still something i don't really get, if i want to display the previous animation i need to Link, every time, the old Actions to the Meshes? There isn't a "Group Actions" functionality?

Comment: if you press the Create New Action button (2 sheets icon), it is creating a new action that is a copy of the previous, but if you decide to make a modification it won't modify the previous action, only the new one. And it is also creating a track in the NLA but it is a stash, meaning it is muted, it is not really playing the action. I don't know why they made that choice though, why automatically pushing a stashed action?